# How to make one var out of six and check if array contains it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am writing "Guess the word game". I am just a beginner in JS / Jquery.

When user clicks "check" button game should find out if array of words contains the word he has made or not but have no clear idea of how to do. Any answers / tips would be appreciated.

```
$( "#start" ).on('click', function(nach) {
    var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * words.length );
    var shuffledWord = words[rand].shuffle();
    for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWord.length; i++ ) {
        $('#Letter1').text(shuffledWord[i]);  
        $('#Letter2').text(shuffledWord[i-1]);  
        $('#Letter3').text(shuffledWord[i-2]);  
        $('#Letter4').text(shuffledWord[i-3]);  
        $('#Letter5').text(shuffledWord[i-4]);  
        $('#Letter6').text(shuffledWord[i-5]);  
    }
    $( "#start" ).attr('disabled',true);
});
```

This is the code that attaches every letter of a 6-length word to a button.
The user clicks on the buttons in order to move and to make a word. 
There is a check button that allows him to check if the array contains his word or not.
Here is my little code with some thoughts.

```
$( "#check" ).on('click', function() {
/*if ( $.inArray ( newword, words ) > -1 ) { // checks if newword is an object of an array
function(uber); // function that returns buttons
} else {
g = g+6;//adds points
function(nach);//starts the game loop again
}*/
});
```

I need to make a var named newword to check if my array contains it or not. 
Any possible solutions would be highly appreciated. I guess it should be done with .join method ? I am not looking for code, just for advice, but anything would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you might already have a couple of bugs in there... e.g. referencing `shuffledWord[i-5]` in a `for i=0..length` loop... could you make a JSFiddle to show your progress so far (include JS and HTML)? Much more likely to get you an answer

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/huRTj/

Comment: the code itself works fine

Comment: Create an empty `newword` string when the game starts/is cleared. Every time a letter is clicked, do `newword += whateverTheNewLetterIs`, to append the new letter to `newword`. That way, when they press `Check`, you'll already have your `newword` variable ready to use / lookup in your array / etc.

Comment: I would also seriously consider refactoring this code as there is a huge amount of repetition which is going to bite you the more you change the code, as you'll be making the same changes in a dozen different places and opening yourself up to making mistakes. Read up on the *DRY* principle. For example, the 160 lines of `#Letter1, 2, ..., 6` click handlers could be reduced down to just one handler of less than a dozen lines. If you want a hand with this, feel free to hit me up on a SO chat once you have 20+ rep

Comment: Sorry, I faced some difficulties with adding letters to my string. Can you please create a short example of how should it work since I got stuck in getting letter after its movement. Thanks in advance !

Comment: I have tried to solve my problem myself. I added the newword+=.. for every click but the problem is with making that string in #423 public, when I write z==0, since there is z  outside, the prog does not work at all, but  wont be able to finish without making it oublic, can u please look thought my code and say where is the fault ? The updated link is here : http://jsfiddle.net/huRTj/1/

Comment: I've looked at your code... I don't know what you think `z` is but I'm pretty sure it's not doing what you think it's doing. You're also misunderstanding the `var` keyword, I think. And your `for(var z=0;......` loop is redundant anyway! When you get to 20 rep (I've just bumped you up to 13), I can help you out in SO chat.

Comment: I think that I have coped with all the problems I had besides the last one. When I try to add the dimension of my button to string it gives nothing and my string stays empty, but when I use alert inside that loop everything works fine.

Comment: Here is a shorter version of your loop from your fiddle which could also be applied to your code in the example above that uses the DRY principle mentioned by @Shai.

    for ( ;i > 0; i-- ) {
        $( "#Letter" + i ).animate({ "right": (925-(i-1)*95) + "px", "top": "319px" }, 1000 );
        $( "#Letter" + i ).attr('disabled',false);
    }